# Flash AS2. Print swf file. 

Tags: flash, printing, actionscript-2

I want to load a swf file and print it using the following code in a button.

```
on (release) {
    var my_pj = new PrintJob();
    var myResult = my_pj.start();
    if (myResult) {
        pagePrint = new MovieClip();
        pagePrint.loadMovie("file-to-print.swf");
        my_pj.addPage(pagePrint);
        my_pj.send();
        delete my_pj;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error or simply nothing happens? From what I gather, you're addPage method is wrong. It should be a String of an instance name like "pagePrint" instead of the reference.

Example:
my_pj.addPage("pagePrint"); // where "pagePrint" is the "instance name" of the object.

Documentation:
http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/PrintJob.html#addPage%28%29

Hope this helps!

Comment: it just doesn't print anything, i believe that the problem is that passing between the loadMovie and the addPage commands is really quick and it doesn't let the swf to load... working on a "onLoad" solution right now